# Phalcon custom DI

Tags: php, phalcon

I've created a new phalcon project which of course has his own Phalcon\Di component inside the index.php file.

Now I would like to know if it's possible to create a second DI that can override some or add some new services to the default DI? So yes, how can I realise this inside my project?

Comment: Would you be doing this for different environments or different URI requests?

Comment: @PaulSCoder I wan’t to pleace the second DI inside a Library folder that I include inside different projects. The environment is almost the same but the URI is different for each project. Do you have a idea to realise this?

Answer (score 1):

I may have misread what you need but have you taken a look at Multi Modules?

https://docs.phalconphp.com/fr/3.2/application

Comment: Is it possible in this way to extend a already defined service from the default DI inside the index? Like: Create a view service inside the project index file and than extend the view service with a new Volt method in a DI class inside /Library/someClass.

Comment: I haven't done this. My view service is defined in each Module.php file. I would look here https://github.com/phalcon/mvc then join and ask here https://forum.phalconphp.com/

Comment: You can have common views like in this example. https://github.com/phalcon/mvc/blob/master/multiple-shared-views/public/index.php